# Add two numbers in django and output will print same on same page

Tags: python, html, django

I'm new to django and I need to add two numbers x and y .

The x and y are inputs from user.

**Here is my views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'name':'keyur'})

def add(request):

    val1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
    val2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
    # red = add('val1','val2')
    res = val1 + val2
    return render(request,'home.html',{'result': res})
```

**Here is my url.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('add', views.add, name='add')

]
```

**Here is my home.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html'  %}

{% block content %}

<h1>hello {{name}} !!!!</h1>
   <form action="add" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
                Enter a 1st number: <input type="text" name="num1"  placeholder="enter the number">
                Enter a 2st number: <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="enter the number">
                <input type="submit">

            </form>


{% endblock %}
```

**Here is my result.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html'  %}

{% block content %}

    Result is... {{result}}

{% endblock %}
```

I want to print the output in same page. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do following:

```
def add(request):
    res = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        val1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
        val2 = int(request.POST['num2'])

        res = val1 + val2
    return render(request,'result.html',{'result': res})
```

Also I'd suggest to change input type from text to number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the `result.html` template when adding the two number

```py
def add(request):

    val1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
    val2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
    # red = add('val1','val2')
    res = val1 + val2
    return render(request,'result.html',{'result': res})
```

you see in the last line, I changed `home.html` to `result.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the following changes in your files:

In views.py, add a condition to check whether you are getting values for num1 and num2, if the values are available then proceed with addition and store the value in result. If the values are not available then make result as None and render the HTML page.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    try:
        if request.POST['num1'] and request.POST['num2']:
            num1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
            num2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
            result = num1+num2
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR",e)
        result = None
    return render(request,"home.html",{"result":result})
```

Similarly, In your home.html,On submitting the values redirect it to the same html page.

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Number 1 <input type=text, name = num1><br>
    Number 2 <input type=text, name = num2><br>
    <input type="Submit" >
    <p>The Result is {{result}}</p>
</form>
```